# How to create constructor for Hashmap<String Boolean> in a factory method?

Tags: java, hashmap, factory

I am creating a factory method for a Hashmap in a public class.

```
 public class MyList {
    Hashmap list = newMap();   //is this function called properly here?

public static final Hashmap newMap() {
    return Hashmap(String, boolean);

  }
 }
```

In the simplest way, how do I set up the factory method if it is to hold a      string and boolean for the key/value pair?

I'm stuck on the syntax.

I just want to return a new Hashmap object and use newMap() as a factory method

Comment: Why use a factoty method ? How is this easier than juste create the object ?

Comment: What is `Hashmap`? Is that your own class? Why is your hashmap assignable to `MyList` type?

Comment: Hashmap is a map type list under Java.util.Hashmap;  I'm just trying to create cleaner code only calling methods in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `HashMap` has generic types for key and value, so you need to specify these types as

   ```
   public static HashMap<String, Boolean> newMap() {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. And inside, you'll create the map as

   - `return new HashMap<String, Boolean>();`
   - or just as `return new HashMap<>();`  using diamond operator (as type is already in the signature
3. You could also pass the type as parameter

   ```
   public static <K, V> HashMap<K, V> newMap(Class<K> classKey, Class<V> classValue) {
       return new HashMap<>();
   }
   ```

---

*Use*

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Boolean> map = newMap();
    Map<Integer, Double> mapID = newMap(Integer.class, Double.class);
}
```

Comment: Is the function call set up as                                                                                          
> myList list = newMap(String, boolean);

Comment: @CodeNewb not sure to understand your question ? Please edit your question up there and clarify

Comment: to give the Hashmap object a name where i call the function, is the syntax correct?  MyList list = newMap();

Comment: @CodeNewb Sorry man, I don't understand nothing at what you want, MyList is your class, HashMap is a java class, there is no link between them at all , and I don't understand what you mean with "give a name"

Comment: if you create a factory method, you have to call the method in the class.  When you create a new Hashmap object you have to give it a name.  When you call the factory method, you have to give the hashmap object that is returned, an object name

Comment: @CodeNewb `Map<String, Boolean> myMap = newMap();` here the name is `myMap` that's it

Answer (score 0):

To get a generic factory method with T and U as Class type you can go ahead with

```
public static <T,U> HashMap<T,U> factoryHashMap(T t , U u ){
         HashMap<T,U> tuHashMap = new HashMap<T,U>();
         // do stuff
        return tuHashMap;
    }
```

Here `T t, Uu` are optional params . You can have empty params too .

If you observe before the return type `HashMap<T,U>` in function, we have put `<T,U>` to denote that this is a generic method

here T and U can be any valid class type . In your case it is String and Boolean

`new HashMap<T,U>` is the instance that is created and updated to your factory method's requirements .

for eg . In the below example we are simply adding `t` and `u` to the map, if they are not null else returning an empty `HashMap`

```
public static <T, U> HashMap<T, U> factoryHashMap(T t, U u) {
    HashMap<T, U> tuHashMap = new HashMap<T, U>();
    if (t != null && u != null)
        tuHashMap.put(t, u);
    return tuHashMap;
}
```

driver method :

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, Boolean> myMap = factoryHashMap("isItCool?",false);
}
```